# Access link page and not folder content of that link

Tags: pages, urls, links

I have a problem with some pages on my site. For example: when i access page called **staff** from **www.example.com/staff** it redirects me to folder **staff** from the root of the site where i have some images and files saved - it shows me the content of folder staff and not the page staff.

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried to resave permalinks structure but did not do anything.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after i posted the question: i need to disable directory browsing.

Just put:

```
Options -Indexes
```

in .htaccess and it's done.